# How can I split on a custom delimiter but escape the delimiter as well in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, csv

I have a string here.

```
Actual_underscore_looks_like_\_
```

Here's some example code that should replace all underscores in the string with spaces:

```
// Use underscores as a delimiter but allow for escaping underscores    
$string = "Actual_underscore_looks_like_\_";
echo str_replace("_"," ",$string);
```

However, it returns `Actual underscore looks like \`. I want `Actual underscore looks like _`. Moreover, I might want to display `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. For this purpose, my input string could be:

`¯\\\_(ツ)\_/¯` How can I accomplish this transformation of text within PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative lookbehind (all underscores that are not preceded by a backslash), then remove the escape:

```
$string = "¯\\\_(ツ)\_/¯";
$result = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)_/', ' ', $string);
$result = preg_replace('/\\\\(\\\\|_)/', '$1', $result);
echo $result;
// => Actual underscore looks like _
```

Comment: Thank you @Amadan :D This is perfect, thanks - I'm going to work on figuring out how this works so I can learn from it and do similar things in the future